# How long does it take for Azure Websites to Autoscale?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5, C#, Razor, EF6.1, SQL Azure

I have been doing some load testing using JMeter, and I have found some surprising results.

I have a test of 30 concurrent users, ramping up over 10 secs. The test plan is fairly simple:

```
1) Login
2) Navigate to page
3) Do query
4) Navigate back
5) Logout.
```

I am using "small" "standard" instances.

I have found that when my Azure setup is configured to "autoscale", it behaves like my test with one "small" instance with no autoscale. When I setup two "small" instances with no autoscale, it goes twice as fast, or rather the average process time per request is 2x, over the test. So it appears that it is NOT autoscaling. I have tried setting the CPU trigger to a lower target ie 40-70. Still no joy.

On further investigation, when "Autoscale" was first introduced, it seems it evaluated the metrics over the previous hour, and now I see references to "10 minutes". I thought that once the CPU started hitting the target value, then it immediately triggered the new instance, which must be the whole point of "autoscale". If I have a burst of concurrent usage, I need the extra instances now, hence a reason for using a PAAS . Since my test took less than 10 minutes, "Autoscale" never kicked in. So what should be the time that Autoscale takes to kick in?

Thanks.

Comment: How long does the test run for?  I have a feeling that the autoscale targets need to be met or exceeded for a small period of time before a new instance is spun up.  From what I can gather in the documentation, Azure checks the metrics once every 5 mins, and then takes action (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/)

Comment: @BrendanGreen, Yes this is useful, and it does reference if app hit peak usage during 5 min period, so in my case I might set it up for 2-4. Just running a test now which I quess will last for 15 mins. After 10 mins, looks like I have just one instance reporting a CPU figure in NewRelic. But I think the facts are there in the article. So need for more testing. Do feel free to post as answer so I can mark up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure will check the CPU metric every 5 minutes, and if it exceeds the threshold that is set, will increase the instance count at that point.

Interestingly, Azure will **decrease** instance counts after 2 hours of remaining below the threshold.

Source: [How to Scale Websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/)

Quoted relevant section:

> Note: When Scale by Metric is enabled, Microsoft Azure checks the CPU
>   of your website once every five minutes and adds instances as needed
>   at that point in time. If CPU usage is low, Microsoft Azure will
>   remove instances once every two hours to ensure that your website
>   remains performant. Generally, putting the minimum instance count at 1
>   is appropriate. However, if you have sudden usage spikes on your
>   website, be sure that you have a sufficient minimum number of
>   instances to handle the load. For example, if you have a sudden spike
>   of traffic during the 5 minute interval before Microsoft Azure checks
>   your CPU usage, your site might not be responsive during that time. If
>   you expect sudden, large amounts of traffic, set the minimum instance
>   count higher to anticipate these bursts.

Comment: Is there a way to identify how Azure Autoscaled? Is there some graph somewhere, that shows what number of instance were instantiated and when, and also when these same instances were decommissioned?

Comment: Have you looked at the operational logs of the website (accessed from the dashboard)?

Comment: My 15 min test has just completed, and from NewRelic, I can only see the one CPU line from the one instance.

Comment: I presume that you have verified that the CPU usage of the site was above 40% (sustained) for more than a 5 min period?

Comment: Just checked the OpLog.... Just the one entry: "PutAutoscaleSetting" which I quess was the initial setup.

Comment: Some other recommended reading:http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/07/scaling-standard-azure-website-to-380k.html and http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/10-things-i-learned-about-rapidly.html.  It is possible that you are not generating enough load.

Comment: So the OpLog is the best place to identify whether autoscale has been triggered?

Comment: The wonderful "Troy Hunt "......!! I think I will leave it here. Need to play abit more. If you could confirm about my OpLog question above then that would be great. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Correct.  See: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/windows-azure-general-availability-of-sql-server-always-on-support-and-notification-hubs-autoscale-improvements-more

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible in the new Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com) to configure scaling based upon different metrics:

- CPU
- Memory usage
- Data in/out
- Http queue length
- Disk Queue length

And also to configure scale up time and scale down time. In the graph it will show you the current amount of instances (solid line) vs your max configured (dashed line) and your configured metrics. When the metric exceeds the line (=configured scale up for that given metric) it will scale up & vica versa.

[image]